# Syntax Error in Android = expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  //LINE16
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Starting to play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
    }     //LINE19
});       //LINE20
```

> Error::
>   LINE 16--Syntax error on token "setOnClickListener", = expected after this token
>   LINE 16--Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
>   LINE 19--Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
>   LINE 20--Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

Comment: you are missing @Override annotation. your code looks fine are you its the right line numbers are you missing curly braces elsewhere?

Comment: could u paste more code, we only guess your problem with these code.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with curly brackets please check each pairs of curly brackets position are right.... other things seems fine with @Override annotation